# cakephp undefined class constant AttachmentBehavior::CROP

Tags: cakephp

Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'AttachmentBehavior::CROP' in /var/www/manage/lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php on line 168.

I have been getting this error after I was done following the steps on this page to setup access control lists. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html .

The error shows up when I deny access to an action which requires authentication. When I grant access to an action, I can use it just fine. The error also shows up on one particular action whether I deny access to it or not.

My version of cakephp is 2.3.4 and I am using the plugin from http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0/ to manage my permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AttachmentBehavior::CROP belongs to a plugin called Uploader which wasn't loaded. problem solved

Comment: I have to wait two days to do that but yes